# How to solve this triple integral (Solid bounded by cone and sphere)

Tags: integration

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this triple integral question?
I been working on it for such a long time, and have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Clearly the hard part it to understand the domain. Using [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) you can get $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi / 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment we use [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).
Also to help you visualize, [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%7Bx%5E2+%3D%3D+y%5E2,x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3D%3D+1%7D,%7Bx,-1,1%7D,%7By,0,1%7D%5D) is a "slice" of the domain. You should imagine that this "roundy cone" revolves 360° around the $z$-axis.

$$0 \leq r \leq 1 \\
0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \\
0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/4$$

we know that $z =r  \cos \phi$ and the jacobian is $r^2 \sin \phi$ therefore the integral of $\iiint f(x,y,z)$ gives :
$$
\int_0^1 dr \int_0^{2\pi}d \theta \int_0^{\pi/4} d \phi\ r \cos  \phi \cdot r^2 \sin \phi = \int_0^1 r^3 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin\phi \cos\phi\ d\phi = \frac14 \cdot 2\pi \cdot \frac14 = \frac{\pi}{8}
$$

Now for the volume we use exactly the same parametrization and simply integrate the function $1$ :
$$
\int_0^1 dr \int_0^{2\pi}d \theta \int_0^{\pi/4} d \phi\ 1 \cdot r^2 \sin \phi = \int_0^1 r^2 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin\phi\  d\phi = \frac13 \cdot 2 \pi \cdot (1- 1/\sqrt{2})
$$
Putting all together and doing some algebra gives you the answer.